Spago failing to install PureScript dependencies due to Git error: 'destination path . already exists and is not an empty directory' on NixOS
I'm trying to get a hello-world Purescript project working on NixOS, and am encountering an error trying to get spago to build it. The installation of dependencies fails with the following error:
[error] 
Failed to install dependency "console"
Git output:

fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.


Aborting installation..
[error] Installation failed
[error] Error:
[error] ExitFailure 1

This seems to occur when spago tries to clone the dependencies (like console and effect) into the current directory (.) instead of the correct subdirectory under .spago. I don't know why git is using . instead of, for example, .spago/console.
I've tried:

Deleting all files and cache, and reinitializing the Spago project
(spago init).
Manually creating the .spago/console directory, and manually cloning
in the dependency.
Unsetting the env vars shown in the shellHook section of shell.nix, below.

Despite these steps, Spago still tries to install dependencies into the project directory . and fails.
Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.
Additional Info:
NixOS environment with a shell.nix configuration:
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.spago
    pkgs.nodejs
    pkgs.purescript
    pkgs.git
    pkgs.strace
    pkgs.purescript-psa
  ];
  shellHook = ''
    unset NIX_ENFORCE_NO_NATIVE
    unset NIX_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    unset NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE
    unset NIX_LDFLAGS
  '';
}

Spago version: 0.21.0
PureScript version: 0.15.15
PSA version: 0.8.2
How do I resolve this, or otherwise, get hello-world Purescript working on nixos?

Have you tried verbose output? What does it say?

@FyodorSoikin The verbose output contains additional debug lines such as this one mentioning the source of the console package.
[debug] Running `globallyCache`: PackageName {packageName = "console"} https://github.com/purescript/purescript-console.git v6.1.0

None of the other debug lines catch my eye as particularly relevant. The line that seems of primary importance is the error:
[error] 
Failed to install dependency "effect"
Git output:

fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.

But it displays without -v.

Well, I'm afraid I can't investigate without looking at your system. I might recommend using spago@next instead. It's officially still in alpha, but I think it's stable enough.

I found a work-around by installing spago locally via npm, instead of using nixos's installation of spago. I used npx to reference npm's spago. Here's what worked for me.

create shell.nix:


{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.nodejs
    pkgs.gmp
  ];
  shellHook = ''
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${pkgs.gmp}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  '';
}



npm install spago --save-dev

Ensure that local version of spago is available: $ npx spago --version
0.21.0

Init: $ npx spago init

build: $ npx spago build


